# How to trim String from the back in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have String like this:

```
"ahfckhs_aidewiofh_asa_rrresf"
```

I have to trim this from the back.

Trimmed `String` would be *`"ahfckhs_aidewiofh_asa"`*.

I have to code retrieving parser with JsonObject.

I think I can code simple parser that has key and value but rev-parser is too much difficult for me.

Comment: Do you want to remove a certain number of characters, or do you want to remove based on some pattern?

Comment: Thank you I am sorry I forgot to write about patterns. <br> I would like to separate String with '_' underscore.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. As Radiodef said, do you want it to be based on some pattern, or just remove the last couple letters?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation for the `String` class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

You can use the `substring` and `lastIndexOf` methods:

```
String str = "ahfckhs_aidewiofh_asa_rrresf";
String trimmed = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("_"));
System.out.println(trimmed);
```

Output:

```
ahfckhs_aidewiofh_asa
```

Comment: This seems like the easiest way to do it.  Although what happens to strings with no "_" in them?

Comment: `lastIndexOf` returns `-1` if the searched string  is not found, so `int u = str.lastIndexOf("_"); String trimmed = (u != -1) ? str.substring(0, u) : str;`

Comment: It's definitely brittle code, but I'm not sure about the exact requirements beyond the simple test case. I think the link to the documentation is the best part of my answer!

Comment: Thank you guys! Now I knew I need to read more APIs... At least I could learn 'lastIndexOf' this time.